# Using bitcoin-core RFCs to create REST APIs

Tags: bitcoin-core, api

I am new to using Bitcoin and the Lightning Network.

I was looking at this: https://bitcoin.org/en/developer-reference#bitcoin-core-apis  I saw REST APIs as well but did not seen any functions for POST, DELTE, etc. Would be realistic to try to make a REST APIs using these functions. One should not have to worry about authorization since the Blockchain is public - right? I wanted to create functionality that would be called when openning/closing a Channel on the Blockchain from the Lightning Network.

Also, I was hoping that in creating a BTCD daemon (and synching it with the Blockchain), one could perhaps have their transactions commit faster. But, it looks as though this can only be done by miners(?) Is my understanding correct?

TIA

Comment: I can't speak too much about the lightning network, but you should be able to build a REST endpoint yourself by utilizing the Bitcoin-Core wallet and the JSON-RPC calls as you referenced. In terms of committing transactions, I assume you want fast confirmation time. A natural way would be paying higher fees, which incites miners to include your transaction sooner. You could potentially pay miners directly to do that, but I found that a little bit unreliable, plus you just can't get away with no extra cost

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response. Should I be a miner? The thought would be  add "open/close" transactions to my block, "solve the puzzle" for it and then place it out there on the Blockchain - does this make sense? This way, one would not have to depend upon another miner to incorporate transactions.

Comment: You don't have to be a miner. All you need is just to broadcast your transaction. As I said, faster confirmation time is achieved by either paying higher fees or pay a miner to include your transaction asap. On a regular computer, you'll probably _never_ be able to miner a block, so becoming a miner is pretty much pointless.

Comment: Thanks again. Out of curiosity, would the confirmation time be much faster on the "testnet" (the testing Blockchain)?